# Joomla custom template error

Tags: templates, joomla

I'm trying to create a custom template at Joomla but I get the following error:

**Error
Unable to write entry
Unable to find install package**

my template Zip ha the following folders:

christinas

-css

--template.css

-js

--template.js

-images

index.php

templateDetails.xml

my templateDetails.xml is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.3" type="template" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>christinas</name>
    <creationDate>Sep 2016</creationDate>
    <author>me</author>

    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2010 - 2016. All rights reserved.</copyright>

    <version>1.1</version>
    <description>My Template</description>

    <positions>
        <position>title</position>
        <position>top1</position>
        <position>top2</position>
        <position>top3</position>
        <position>logo</position>
        <position>menu</position>
        <position>search</position>
        <position>slide</position>

    </positions>

    <files>
        <file>index.php</file>
        <file>templateDetails.xml</file>
        <folder>css/</folder>
        <folder>images/</folder>
        <folder>js/</folder>

    </files>

</extension>
```

Which is the proper fileset for a joomla template?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt it be

```
<filename>index.php</filename>
```